# BizTalk SpreadsheetDocument.Open Stream: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: biztalk, pipeline, import-from-excel

I am trying to build a custom pipeline which will be able to read an Excel file.
When I run this code on Windows 7 - it works fine.
When I run the code on Win 2k8 - I get an error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array." (it fails when trying to open the stream).

if I test the component on both boxes (load a file and process it) - it works fine.
The error only happens when it comes directly from BizTalk via File adapter.

if i change the code to load a file (regardless of what is coming in from the pipeline) - it works fine!

Any Ideas?

```
public Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext pc, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage inmsg)
    {            

    var excelAsStream = inmsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();

    try
    {

        //excelAsStream.Position = 0;
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelAsStream, false))  // Here I get the Error
        {
```

Comment: Can you post the code of SpreadsheetDocument.Open method

Comment: I could add the code, but the code failed on the "open" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far to fix the issue, I have done the following:

1. read excel file as Stream
2. save it locally with ".tmp" extension
3. Read tmp file and covert to xml
4. delete tmp file
5. Pass message to MessageBox

Code:

```
var fullFileName = string.Empty; // tmp file name to be loaded via spreadsheet
IBaseMessageContext context = inmsg.Context;

try

{
if (inmsg.BodyPart == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("inmsg.BodyPart","Incoming Message is not Valid stream");


var srcFileName = context.Read("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties").ToString();
// write file to local folder as tmp
var fileTmp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(srcFileName);
var pathTmp = Path.GetDirectoryName(srcFileName) ?? string.Empty;
fullFileName = Path.Combine(pathTmp, fileTmp + ".tmp");

var excelAsStream = inmsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream(); // get the msg as Stream
using (var fileStream = File.Create(fullFileName))
{
    excelAsStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    excelAsStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}


using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fullFileName, false))
{   
    // Do code here
}

} // end try
```